# Reverse Polish Calculator in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to build a reverse polish calculator in Python and this is as far as I've gotten.  It seems to work until I try to run PRT, at which point I get the last number from the text file instead of the result that was appended to the stack from the previous calculation.  Python is not my normal language, so I apologize for what you're about to see.

```
    def is_number(ln):
        try:
            int(ln)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def main():
        stack = []
        # Open file
        infile = open('math.txt', 'r')

        line = infile.readline()

        while line != '':
            if is_number(line):
                line = int(line)
                stack.append(line)
            if line in ['ADD', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'DIV']:
                if line=='ADD': result = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
                if line=='SUB': result = stack.pop() - stack.pop()
                if line=='MUL': result = stack.pop() * stack.pop()
                if line=='DIV': result = stack.pop() / stack.pop()
                print(result)
                stack.append(result)
            if line=='PRT': print(stack.pop())
            if line=='STOP': exit()
            line = infile.readline()

        # Close file
        infile.close()

    # Call main function

    main()
```

math.txt:

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    ADD
    PRT
```

I'm guessing maybe the issue is to do with the newline character or the readline, but I just don't write in Python normally, so I'm unsure.

Comment: Can you post your math.txt.

Comment: Once you have fixed your code, I made you [this gist](https://gist.github.com/spectras/dabae78e0e94a58793b8) with a more pythonic version of what you do, so you can compare. Probably not perfect, but leverages the power of python for clearer code. Requires python3.

Comment: @BarunSharma  I added my math.txt file

Comment: @spectras That file is awesome, but a bit out of my league for this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline()` returns the line including the trailing lf or crlf, so I'm not really sure how this partly worked unless you just changed a raw_input into a file read.  In any case, the shortest distance between your program and working code **on that dataset** is to strip the line.  You could just do an rstrip with your current data, but I'd just strip both sides.  Modify your program like this:

```
     while line != '':
+        line = line.strip()
         if is_number(line):
             line = int(line)
```

But that still isn't very robust.  Here is a modified version that processes the lines first and then runs your same algorithm.  But I would encourage you to study and understand the gist provided by spectras in the comments, because it shows a lot more useful Python idioms than this:

```
def is_number(ln):
    try:
        int(ln)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def main():
    with open('math.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = (line.strip() for line in f)
        lines = [line for line in lines if line]

    stack = []
    for line in lines:
        if is_number(line):
            stack.append(int(line))
        elif line in ['ADD', 'SUB', 'MUL', 'DIV']:
            if line=='ADD': result = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
            if line=='SUB': result = stack.pop() - stack.pop()
            if line=='MUL': result = stack.pop() * stack.pop()
            if line=='DIV': result = stack.pop() / stack.pop()
            print(result)
            stack.append(result)
        elif line=='PRT':
            print(stack.pop())
        elif line=='STOP':
            exit()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unknown line: %s" % line)

# Call main function

main()
```

Comment: Thank you!  My struggle with the solution provided by gist is converting it to Python 2.  I just haven't spent enough time with the language to do so.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/misc/blob/master/postfix.py) is my implementation of a postfix expression evaluator.

This code expects the expression in the form of a whitespace separated string. You could make that with;

```
with open('math.txt') as f:
    expr = f.read()
```

The most useful trick in this code is to use a dictionary to map operator names to functions. For example the operators with two arguments;

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv, pow

_binops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv, '**': pow}
```

This replaces all the `if` statements with;

```
b, a = stk.pop(), stk.pop()
stk.append(_binops[i](a, b))
```

Using `_binops[i]` selects a function object from the dictionary.
This function object is called with the values popped from the stack.

An interactive example in IPython;

```
In [1]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv, pow
:_binops = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv, '**': pow}
:--

In [2]: _binops['+']
Out[2]: <function _operator.add>

In [3]: _binops['+'](1, 2)
Out[3]: 3
```

The full code as shown on github also implements some operators that take only one argument like trigonometric functions, and provides some constants.

It could be easily modified to also accept `ADD` instead of `+`, just by changing the `_binops` dictionary;

```
_binops = {'+': add, 'add': add, '-': sub, 'sub': sub,
           '*': mul, 'mul': mul, '/': truediv, 'div': truediv,
           '**': pow, 'pow': pow}
```